# Magento 2.3 issue admin page not rendering

Tags: installation, magento2.3

**I tried to install Magento New Release 2.3** , installed successfully
 but here **Magento Admin Login** Page not rendering even Home page working fine. Some error are i am
 mentioning below please if any solution is please guide me.

**Here generated folder deleted,cache,upgrade,deploy,compile everything
is done but no solution.**

[image]

Comment: let me know are u facing any problem with frontend?

Answer (score 3):

It's causing you problem due to you are on windows.

Give a try to below workaround.

> ```
> Find : /vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template/File/Validator.php:139
>
> find : 
> foreach ($directories as $directory) {
>     if (0 === strpos($realPath, $directory)) {
>         return true;
>     }
> }
>
> Replace with:
> foreach ($directories as $directory) {
>     $realDirectory = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($directory);
>     // and replace `$directory` with `$realDirectory`
>     if (0 === strpos($realPath, $realDirectory)) {
>         return true;
>     }
> }
> ```

UPDATE :

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/19480#issue-386162790

Its working for me too.

Comment: its core file but directly this way its not recommended to work

Comment: Hi @webdeveloper but frontend not getting home page https://prnt.sc/lpssgn and at admin page https://prnt.sc/lpst7h windows please advise

Comment: @hiteshbalpande, I know its causing you a problem because You are on windows system and windows use '/' for seprator and linux uses '\' So if you are on windows than you have to do this. Its core bug reported on Git Also.

Comment: Give up vote and mark accepted answer if its helpful to you.

Comment: @Vivek, any patches are available for it? without touching vendor file can we resolve this issue?

Comment: @jafarpinjar, No patches available you can override file in your module. or Use Linux !!! As Magento sugggested in git issue. #19480

Comment: @Vivek, can you please share it, github link is not override with the module

Comment: @jafarpinjar, You have do it by your self. Cause I didn't get this issue. I'm on linux too.