# Magento 2.3: how to fix blank admin page not rendering

Tags: magento2, admin, magento2.3

[image]
I have installed magento 2.3 latest version, But I never login in admin panel.

Comment: please check: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252188/magento-2-2-7-admin-panel-blank-page

Comment: I got the solution here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252219/magento-2-3-issue-admin-page-not-rendering

Answer (score 9):

I am new to magento, I faced the same problem and found the follwoing solution:

**Magento 2.3.1**
File Location:

```
xampp/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template/File/Validator.php
```

Code:

```
public function isValid($filename)
{
    $filename = str_replace('\\', '/', $filename);
    if (!isset($this->_templatesValidationResults[$filename])) {
        $this->_templatesValidationResults[$filename] =
            ($this->isPathInDirectories($filename, $this->_compiledDir)
                || $this->isPathInDirectories($filename, $this->moduleDirs)
                || $this->isPathInDirectories($filename, $this->_themesDir)
                || $this->_isAllowSymlinks)
            && $this->getRootDirectory()->isFile($this->getRootDirectory()->getRelativePath($filename));
    }
    return $this->_templatesValidationResults[$filename];
}
```

To Replace with this simple code:

```
public function isValid($filename)
{
   return true;
}
```

It works for me and hope will work for someone like me.

Comment: Good its worked for me. Thanks. But, Is it make any trouble infuture on any work?

Comment: THanks man, you saved a day!

Comment: Worked for me. Nice answer.

Answer (score 4):

This is Magento bug. Wrong paths to Windows are generated. The fixed fix is

**Magento 2.3.0**

```
#/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template/File/Validator.php:114
```

the string

> $realPath = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path);

to replace

> $realPath = str_replace('\', '/',
>   $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));

**Magento 2.2.7**

```
/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template/File/Validator.php:113
```

code

```
protected function isPathInDirectories($path, $directories)
{
    if (!is_array($directories)) {
        $directories = (array)$directories;
    }
    foreach ($directories as $directory) {
        if (0 === strpos($this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path), $directory)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

to replace

```
protected function isPathInDirectories($path, $directories)
    {
        $realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));
        if (!is_array($directories)) {
            $directories = (array)$directories;
        }
        foreach ($directories as $directory) {
            if (0 === strpos($realPath, $directory)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Go to /vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template/File/Validator.php then find this code

```
$realPath = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path);
```

Now replace it with the below code.

```
$realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to  delete files and folder from following location :

```
rm -rf root/pub/static/adminhtml root/pub/static/frontend root/pub/static/deployed_version.txt
```

- Give proper permission to static folder
- Run following command :

  bin/magento  setup:upgrade
  bin/magento  setup:di:compile
  bin/magento  setup:static-content:deploy

May be issue is static file are not deployed properly , above step will regenerate static files .
Thanks

Comment: There are some situation , when templates are not generated fully , and cause blank page issue , at least I faced this issue , So with due respect, may I know your opinion why you did negative vote , could you justify your verdict . Thanks