# Store configuration page is blank

Tags: magento2

I moved moved my working site from stg to live. The configurations was working fine before after moving to live, the store page is blank. The leftbar, and header showing properly but body part is empty. There is no errors in the console. I checked the logs also, no clue.

What I tried:

- Checked all folder permissions
- Tried following commands

  `php bin/magento setup:upgrade php bin/magento setup:di:compile php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f php bin/magento cache:flush`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Also happened with me. From my notes, I did the following sequence:

- bin/magento setup:upgrade
- bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
  pt_BR en_US -f
- bin/magento setup:di:compile
- bin/magento indexer:reindex
- bin/magento cache:flush
- bin/magento cache:clean

From your attempt, you are missing the reindex command.

I would recommend clearing your browser's cash or try an incognito section.

After this, if the error persists, you may check exception.log and system.log to get more details about the error.

From what I know, it may also be related to a conflict with plugins or extensions installed. You may temporarily disable one or two if you have any.

Good luck

Comment: Sorry for the delay. The above is not solved the issue.

Comment: So, it is most likely related to your PHP version. Please check if your PHP version in the server reflects the PHP version you configured your website.

Comment: I also find these links in the google. Hope they may also help.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/256337/magento-2-3-how-to-fix-blank-admin-page-not-rendering
https://meetanshi.com/blog/solved-magento-2-2-7-and-2-3-admin-page-blank-issue/